# AngularJS wait for all async calls inside foreach finish?

Tags: angularjs

I try to get all the data after finishing foreach loop but somehow always get []

```
 $scope.temp = [];
    angular.forEach(seasonStageIds, function (seasonStageId, index) {

        playerService.getPlayerProfile(seasonStageId, $stateParams.params.playerSename).then(function (data) {

            playerService.getPlayerPositionPerSeason(seasonStageId, data.data.Id).then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                _.chain(data)
                 .groupBy('Position')
                 .map(function (value, key) {

                     var goals = _.reduce(value, function (memo, num) {
                         return memo + num.Goals;
                     }, 0);
                     var apps = _.reduce(value, function (memo, num) {

                         return memo + num.Apps;
                     }, 0);
                     var assists = _.reduce(value, function (memo, num) {
                         return memo + num.Assist;
                     }, 0);
                     var ratings = _.reduce(value, function (memo, num) {
                         return memo + num.Rating;
                     }, 0);

                     var position = {
                         Position: key,
                         Apps: apps,
                         Assists: assists,
                         Ratings: ratings,
                         Goals: goals                        
                     };       
                     console.log(position);          >> correct data
                     $scope.temp.push(position);
                 });
            });


        });
    });


    $q.all($scope.temp).then(function (data) {
        console.log( data);   >> show []
    })
```

What did I do wrong ?
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$q.all` works with promises only! I.e. wait for all all the promises to complete then run the 'then' function. You are passing an array as the argument. To get what you want, try the following:

```
$scope.temp = [];
angular.forEach(seasonStageIds, function (seasonStageId, index) {

    var promise =  playerService.getPlayerProfile(seasonStageId, $stateParams.params.playerSename).then(function (data) {

        return playerService.getPlayerPositionPerSeason(seasonStageId, data.data.Id).then(function (data) {
            return _.chain(data)
             .groupBy('Position')
             .map(function (value, key) {

                 var goals = _.reduce(value, function (memo, num) {
                     return memo + num.Goals;
                 }, 0);
                 var apps = _.reduce(value, function (memo, num) {

                     return memo + num.Apps;
                 }, 0);
                 var assists = _.reduce(value, function (memo, num) {
                     return memo + num.Assist;
                 }, 0);
                 var ratings = _.reduce(value, function (memo, num) {
                     return memo + num.Rating;
                 }, 0);

                 var position = {
                     Position: key,
                     Apps: apps,
                     Assists: assists,
                     Ratings: ratings,
                     Goals: goals                        
                 };       

                 return position;
             });
        });
    });

    $scope.temp.push(promise);
});


$q.all($scope.temp).then(function (data) {
    console.log( data);
});
```

E.g. http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19677/